# FFmpeg trimming audio and adjusting volume

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to edit audio and change its volume using FFmpeg.
Here is my command:
`-af adelay=1000|1000` delay audio by one sec
`-af volume=2dB` change its volume
They both work fine, but I can only choose either of them to apply on the command, can I do both of them?

update:
Here is the full command I'm using. It mixes and trims two audios into the video.

```
C:\Users\ffmpeg.exe -y -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i C:\Users\Scene1_%03d.png -ss 0.0 -t 5.2 -i C:\Users\sound01.wav -ss 3.466666666666667 -t 5.2 -i C:\Users\sound02.wav -filter_complex "[1] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a1]; [a1]adelay=1700.0|1700.0,apad,volume=0.1dB[b1]; [2] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a2]; [a2]adelay=5000.0|5000.0,volume=0.1dB[b2]; [b1][b2]amerge=2[a]" -map 0:v -map [a] -b:v 2800k -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 -ac 2 C:\Users\test.mp4
```

I would like to add `volume=0.1dB` into filter_complex, but I'm getting this error:

> [Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0000025f0dc1d3c0] No channel layout for input 1
>       Last message repeated 1 times
>   [AVFilterGraph @ 0000025f0db2ef00] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_7
>   Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
>   Error reinitializing filters!
>   Failed to inject frame into filter network: I/O error
>   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0
>   Conversion failed!
>   :0

Comment: Please include the *full* command-line output, not just the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my post.
`volume` should be written before `aformat`, like so

```
-filter_complex "[1] volume=0.1dB,aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do both… separate them by a comma:

```
-af "adelay=1000|1000,volume=2dB"
```

See the [filtering guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, it works when I only have one audio, if I want to use it in filter-complex, it didn't work.

Comment: Like this `-filter_complex "[1] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a1]; [a1]adelay=1700.0|1700.0,volume=0.1dB[b1]`

Comment: Please be more specific about “it didn't work”. If you have an actual example, please edit your question and include the full command you are trying, and the full command line output including any errors you get.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I edited my post, please check it out.